# Turn off highlighting a certain pattern in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In vim, I am editing a file of filetype "markdown", but which contains latex math expressions such as $x_i$. Vim's syntax highlighting for markdown thinks the pattern *_* (letter-underscore-letter) is an error, and highlights the underscore in such patterns bright red. I would like to turn this off by adding a line to my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.Rmd "Dear vim, please don't highlight the pattern *_*"
```

What is the appropriate command to do that? Is it possible at all to do that in .vimrc, without editing a syntax file?

Note: I want to keep the markdown syntax highlighting in general, only turn off that particular feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to modify the Markdown syntax for that. One way would be to remove the parsing of the error:

```
:syn clear markdownError
```

But that would cause the other syntax rules to start an *italic* section on that `_` char. Better just clear the error highlighting with:

```
:hi link markdownError Normal
```

To maintain the general error highlighting, but only define exceptions for the special `$x_i$` string, define an overriding syntax group; luckily, this is easy because no existing syntax is there:

```
:syn match markdownIgnore "\$x_i\$"
```

(Adapt the regular expression to match all possible math expressions.)
This needs to be put into `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` to be executed *after* the original syntax script.

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there a way to apply this to the specific pattern only? (I will accept your answer otherwise)

Comment: That's indeed better; I've added that.

Comment: This also works in vimrc. The line I put in is `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.Rmd,*.rmd :syn match markdownIgnore "\$.*_.*\$"`

Comment: ... after the line `autocmd *.Rmd,*.rmd set filetype=markdown`

Comment: Try `:autocmd Syntax markdown syn match markdownIgnore "\$x_i\$"`, but this must come after the `:syn on` in your `.vimrc`. If that still doesn't work, try prepending `:autocmd VimEnter * ...` to it.

Comment: Your approach goes around the built-in filetype detection and won't work on explicit `:setfiletype markdown` or `:setl syntax=markdown`. That may be fine for you, but you've been warned.

Comment: Another recommendation: Putting everything into `.vimrc` doesn't scale; you'll end up with a very long monster sooner or later. Better use the facilities for encapsulation that Vim offers.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to remove `_` from the markdown error pattern, you can redefine it. In my case I want to turn off error notifications of underscores in a word as I put a lot of URLs in my documents.

There's a line that defines the error pattern inside `syntax/markdown.vim` file

```
" Original error pattern
syn match markdownError "\w\@<=_\w\@="
```

Remove the `_` from the pattern and add that to `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`.

```
" New error pattern without the underscore
syn match markdownError "\w\@<=\w\@="
```

Comment: I have added the changed file in `after/syntax` but it is still giving the error for underscores

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Still?

Comment: `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax` for neovim btw :) worked perfectly for me

Comment: This works for vim-8.1 on OSX 10.15.7.  The accepted solution does not work for me.

Comment: Adding `" 2022-10-19 prevent "_" highlight in .Rmd files`
`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.Rmd,*.rmd syn match markdownIgnore "\w\@<=\w\@="` in the .vimrc file worked for me.

Comment: If you use homebrew like me, you may have your markdown.vim in a location like this: `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/9.0.1250/share/vim/vim90/syntax/markdown.vim`.