# Disable ampersand error highlighting in vim on HTML5 files

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

In vim, is it possible to disable error highlighting for ampersand (&) symbols used by itself?

[image]

Comment: It is practically an error writing literal `&`, what you should write instead is: `&amp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this :

```
:hi Error NONE
```

It disables error highlighting.

If you want to do it only for a pattern(like `&`) then [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137601/turn-off-highlighting-a-certain-pattern-in-vim).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have followed the link and used `syn match htmlIgnore "&"` on `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good to know it helped :)